# Como faço para adicionar horas a uma hora

Tags: php

Bom tenho a seguinte hora em uma variável:

```
$x = "10:15";
```

Tenho duas questões diferentes,

1. Como faço para adicionar 30 minutos a esta hora.
2. Como faço para adicionar 1 hora a esta hora.

Obrigado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon vale a pena. Feliz natal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para adicinar uma hora podes fazer assim:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('10:15') + 60*60;
$dataHora = strftime('%d - %m - %Y, %H:%M', $timestamp); // 24 - 12 - 2016, 11:15
```

Para adicionar 30 mins:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('10:15') + 60*30;
$dataHora = strftime('%d - %m - %Y, %H:%M', $timestamp); // 24 - 12 - 2016, 10:45
```

strtotime retorna o numero de secs

Podes ver mais aqui sobre a formatação que queres http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Vai dormir Miguel. Está tarde em Portugal.

Comment: É isso mesmo, já agora como faço para adicionar 1 dia a uma data, (Só para não ter que tar a criar uma nova pergunta).

Comment: @Gumball haha, tens razão

Comment: É isso mesmo, já agora como faço para adicionar 1 dia a uma data, (Só para não ter que tar a criar uma nova pergunta)

Comment: @Gonçalo faz pela mesma logica, é isto: `...strtotime('10:15') + (60 * 60 * 24);`

Comment: @Gonçalo, `strtotime` retorna o num de secs é só multiplicares

Comment: Mas como faço, para exibit a data em uma variavel? Desculpa la a massada eheh.

Comment: @Gonçalo depois fazes: `strftime('%d - %m - %Y, %G:%i', $time);`

Comment: Já percebi a lógica, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tem um jeito simples que é:

`$date = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+30 minutes'));
echo $date;`

Para adicionar 1 hora:

`$date_1_hora = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+1 Hours'));
echo $date_1_hora;`